# Webpack sass where is the css file

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, webpack

I am using web pack with sass loader like this:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: "style!css!sass"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

But i see the styles apply to the style tag, where is the generate css file?

Comment: Where to definde style.scss path?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

By default, the style-loader inlines the compiled css into your bundle, which are added to the head of the page with the output file e.g. `bundle.js`. Using the [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin) you can remove the compiled css from the bundle, and export it to a separate file.

First - wrap your loader in the plugin:

```
 loaders: [{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
    "style",
    "css!sass")
 }]
},
```

Then tell the plugin what to call the file it generates:

```
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("app.css")
 ]
```

Include this file in your HTML normally.

Comment: Be warned that this kills Hot Module Replacement functionality

Comment: Yes this will kill HMR but don't forget you don't *need* to do this every time. You could only run this plugin in a production webpack configuration.

Comment: @adc do we really need style loader in this case? it could be just loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
    "css!sass")
 }]

Comment: I don't think that's how the ExtractText plugin works. You would still need to include the style loader.

Comment: I have bunch of scss files. Is there a way for me to create bunch of css files from them?

Comment: @adc You said `include file in html normally`, what if I use extractTextPlugin in `production` mode and `style-loder` in `dev` mode? is there any way to add `<link href="extracted.css">` tag automatically in `production` mode?

Answer (score 7):

If you want a separate CSS file when using Webpack, you need to use the [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin).

Answer (score 2):

The extract-text-webpack-plugin has been deprecated you should use the [mini-css-extract-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin).  Assuming you have your styles in `css/app.scss`, your entry file should import it as usual like:

```js
import 'css/app.scss';
```

Add the plugin:

```
plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin()]
```

And add the plugin to your loader chain:

```
{
  test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
  use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
}
```

When you run webpack with that configuration you'll end up with an `app.css` file loaded in your HTML with a tag similar to:

```html
<link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet">
```