# Webpack combine sass components into one css file

Tags: sass, webpack

I have the following in my react component:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/js/');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'jsx');

var config = {
    entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: 'app.js'
    },
    module : {
        loaders : [
            {
                test : /\.jsx?/,
                include : APP_DIR,
                loader : 'babel'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
            },
            {
              test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png)$/,
              loader: 'url-loader?limit=30000&name=[name]-[hash].[ext]'
            }
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

is it possible to combine all of the scss components into one .css file? Currently they are inserted inline because of me doing this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {render} from 'react-dom';

import axios from 'axios';

import Forms from './forms/forms.jsx';

import './../public/sass/typography.scss';
import './../public/sass/main.scss';
import './../public/sass/navigation.scss';
import './../public/sass/buttons.scss';
import './../public/sass/forms.scss';
import './../public/sass/icons.scss';
import './../public/sass/layout.scss';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webpack sass where is the css file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29210325/webpack-sass-where-is-the-css-file)